# Fastest way to check which dates exist in another pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two datetime columns in different dataframes, one of general dates and one of holiday dates.
I want to add a new column to the first dataframe stating whether or not the date in that row is a holiday.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [pd.Timestamp("2018-01-01"), pd.Timestamp("2018-01-02")]})
holidays = pd.DataFrame({'date': [pd.Timestamp("2018-01-01"), pd.Timestamp("2018-12-25")]})
```

This is my current method:

```
holiday_dates = holidays.date
df['holiday'] = df.date.map(lambda x: sum(holiday_dates.isin([x])) > 0)
```

It works, giving the desired output below but is incredibly slow for my data set of around 100,000 entries.

```
In[]: df
Out[]:
        date  holiday
0 2018-01-01     True
1 2018-01-02    False
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this operation?

Comment: I'd say this is not a duplicate as it is about finding a more efficient, not just asking how to do something. Although the answers to both are the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to add a new column to the first dataframe stating whether or not the date in that row is a holiday.

You should be able to use `.isin()` directly for this:

```
In [7]: df['holiday'] = df['date'].isin(holidays['date'])                       

In [8]: df                                                                      
Out[8]: 
        date  holiday
0 2018-01-01     True
1 2018-01-02    False
```

Comment: I benchmarked this as taking `0.04s` compared to the original `647s`. A definite improvement!